# EGit automatically add new files

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

When executing a commit of a set of files within the EGit eclipse plugin, I always have to add new files manually in the commit dialog

[image: Commit dialog]

Is there a way to configure the plugin in a way, that adding new files automatically is the default setting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Such an option exists now, it can be enabled in the preferences in *Team* → *Git* → *Commit Dialog* by checking *Include selected untracked files*:

[image: Include selected untracked files option in commit dialog preferences]

Note that only untracked files that are contained in the selected files/folders/projects are included – so it depends on where you opened the context menu from.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, there doesn't seem to be any option to have all new files added automatically.
(and this wouldn't be possible as well with Git)

Even on the commit stage, Git proposes only `git commit -a -m "..."` in order to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, **but new files you have not told git about are not affected**.

In other word, this would be a new feature in EGit which wouldn't have any direct correspondence in Git.

Comment: Well, id doesn't have to be directly connected to an underlaying Git feature. Right now I have to manually select the new files (or click to select all button at the topright) so everything the plugin needed to do would be to precheck the checkbox.

Comment: @perdian: I completely agree the Egit GUI doesn't need to have an exact match in Git feature, but my point is: if that isn't available *at all* in Git, maybe that means such a feature might have been considered as not such a good idea. That being said, having it as an option would be nice.