# Eclipse/EGit: mark project as modified when new files are added

Tags: eclipse, egit

Is it possible to have Eclipse mark projects as "modified" in the package explorer (with the ">" symbol) when new files have been added, not just when old files have been modified? According to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677318/egit-automatically-add-new-files) it is not possible to automatically commit new files, but being notified about them would also be useful.

Can it be done? If so, how?

Comment: That should actually work already. Are you using an older version of EGit? Please install 2.2 from the following update site: http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

Comment: Regarding the other question, there's now an option for that, see my new answer there.

Comment: Update to 2.2 did the job, thanks!

Comment: Ok. I posted the comment as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should actually work already.

Are you using an older version of EGit? Please install 2.2 from the following update site:

http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates